# AutoIT - winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1 MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 large download fail

Tags: xmlhttprequest, autoit, winhttprequest

I have a problem with winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1 & MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 for download large bin file.
My code :

```
;Droit Admin
#RequireAdmin

;Handler Error
Global $__g_oHTTP_ErrorHandler = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error", __HTTP_OnError)

$local = @DesktopDir & "\test.bin"
$lien = "https://mylink1-26Mb"
;$lien = "https://mylink2-11Mb"

$oHTTP = ObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

;First Connection with SSO authenticate
$url = "https://sso.authenticate"
$target = "https://domain"
$body = "USER=ABCD1234&PASSWORD=AZERTY&target=" & $target
$oHTTP = ObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
$oHTTP.Open("POST", $url, False)
$oHTTP.Send($body)

;Print
ConsoleWrite($oHTTP.Status & @CR)
ConsoleWrite($oHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders & @CR)
```

> Console :
>
> 200
> Cache-Control: no-cache, private
> Connection: Keep-Alive Date: Thu,25 Aug 2022 07:12:25 GMT
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
> Pragma: no-cache
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
> Expires: -1
> Server: Apache
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> X-Vcap-Request-Id: ############################

```
;Request HEAD to obtain size file
$oHTTP.Open("HEAD", $lien, False)
$oHTTP.Send()

;Print
$size_cloud_file = $oHTTP.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length")
ConsoleWrite($oHTTP.Status & @CR)
ConsoleWrite($oHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders & @CR)
```

> Console :
>
> 200
> Cache-Control: no-cache, private
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2022 07:12:25 GMT
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
> Pragma: no-cache
> qr> Content-Length: 26683497
> Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
> Expires: 0
> Server: Apache
> Content-Description: File Transfer
> Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.bin
> X-Vcap-Request-Id: ########################

```
;Download File
$oHTTP.Open("GET", $lien, False)
$oHTTP.Send()

;Print all values
Consolewrite("#Status                           : " & $oHTTP.Status & @CR)
Consolewrite("#Status Text                      : " & $oHTTP.StatusText & @CR)
Consolewrite("#GetAllResponseHeaders            : " & @CR & $oHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders & @CR)
;Consolewrite("Response Text                   : " & $oHTTP.ResponseText & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(0)) Then Consolewrite("#UserAgentString                   : " & $oHTTP.option(0) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(1)) Then Consolewrite("#URL                               : " & $oHTTP.option(1) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(2)) Then Consolewrite("#URLCodePage                       : " & $oHTTP.option(2) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(3)) Then Consolewrite("#EscapePercentInURL                : " & $oHTTP.option(3) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(4)) Then Consolewrite("#SslErrorIgnoreFlags               : " & $oHTTP.option(4) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(5)) Then Consolewrite("#SelectCertificate                 : " & $oHTTP.option(5) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(6)) Then Consolewrite("#EnableRedirects                   : " & $oHTTP.option(6) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(7)) Then Consolewrite("#UrlEscapeDisable                  : " & $oHTTP.option(7) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(8)) Then Consolewrite("#UrlEscapeDisableQuery             : " & $oHTTP.option(8) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(9)) Then Consolewrite("#SecureProtocols                   : " & $oHTTP.option(9) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(10)) Then Consolewrite("#EnableTracing                     : " & $oHTTP.option(10) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(11)) Then Consolewrite("#RevertImpersonationOverSsl        : " & $oHTTP.option(11) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(12)) Then Consolewrite("#EnableHttpsToHttpRedirects        : " & $oHTTP.option(12) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(13)) Then Consolewrite("#EnablePassportAuthentication      : " & $oHTTP.option(13) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(14)) Then Consolewrite("#MaxAutomaticRedirects             : " & $oHTTP.option(14) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(15)) Then Consolewrite("#MaxResponseHeaderSize             : " & $oHTTP.option(15) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(16)) Then Consolewrite("#MaxResponseDrainSize              : " & $oHTTP.option(16) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(17)) Then Consolewrite("#EnableHttp1_1                     : " & $oHTTP.option(17) & @CR)
if ($oHTTP.option(18)) Then Consolewrite("#EnableCertificateRevocationCheck  : " & $oHTTP.option(18) & @CR)
```

> Console :
>
> #Status                           : 200
> #Status Text                      : OK
> #GetAllResponseHeaders            :
> Cache-Control: no-cache, private
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2022 07:12:26 GMT
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=96
> Pragma: no-cache
> Content-Length: 26683497
> Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
> Expires: 0
> Server: Apache
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Content-Description: File Transfer
> Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.bin
> X-Vcap-Request-Id: ######################################
>
> #UserAgentString                   : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Win32; WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5)
> #URL                               : https://mylink1-26Mb
> #URLCodePage                       : 65001
> #EnableRedirects                   : True
> #UrlEscapeDisableQuery             : True
> #RevertImpersonationOverSsl        : True
> #MaxAutomaticRedirects             : 10
> #MaxResponseHeaderSize             : 65536
> #MaxResponseDrainSize              : 1024000
> #EnableHttp1_1                     : True

```
;Copy ResponseBody to bin local file
FileDelete($local)
$handle = FileOpen($local, 18)
FileWrite($handle, $oHTTP.ResponseBody)         ;=> ResponseBody empty or not exist
FileClose($handle)

Func __HTTP_OnError($oError)
    ConsoleWrite(@ScriptName & " (" & $oError.scriptline & ") : ==> COM Error intercepted !" & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.number is: " & @TAB & @TAB & "0x" & Hex($oError.number) & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.windescription:" & @TAB & $oError.windescription & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.description is: " & @TAB & $oError.description & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.source is: " & @TAB & @TAB & $oError.source & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.helpfile is: " & @TAB & $oError.helpfile & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.helpcontext is: " & @TAB & $oError.helpcontext & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.lastdllerror is: " & @TAB & $oError.lastdllerror & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.scriptline is: " & @TAB & $oError.scriptline & @CRLF & _
            @TAB & "err.retcode is: " & @TAB & "0x" & Hex($oError.retcode) & @CRLF & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>_MyCOMErrFunc
```

If i use the same script with a 11Mb file, there are no problem !
It's same error with COM : "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0"

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

I use https://github.com/dragana-r/autoit-winhttp
Thanks to @dragana

```
#include <WinHttpConstants.au3>
#include <WinHttp.au3>

Func Download($lien,$local,$progressbar)

    ;Check compatibility with windows
    If Not _WinHttpCheckPlatform() Then
       ConsoleWrite("WinHTTP not compatible" & @CR)
       Return "WinHTTP not compatible"
    EndIf

    $sProxy = "my_proxy:my_port"
    $sProxyBypass = "my_proxy_local_bypass"
    $url = "https://sso.authenticate"
    $target = "https://domain"
    $body = "USER=ABCD1234&PASSWORD=AZERTY&target=" & $target

    ;First connexion POST
    ;OPEN
    $hOpen = _WinHttpOpen("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240", _
                          $WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NAMED_PROXY, _
                          $sProxy, _
                          $sProxyBypass)
    if @error Then
       ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpOpen :" & @error & @CR)
       Return "ERREUR : WinHttpOpen"
    EndIf

    ;CONNECT
    $hConnect = _WinHttpConnect($hOpen, $url, $INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT)
    if @error Then
       ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpConnect1 : " & @error)
       Return "ERREUR : WinHttpConnect1"
    EndIf

    ;REQUEST SEND
    $hRequest =  _WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest($hConnect, "POST", $surl, $WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, $body)
    if @error Then
       ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest1 : " & @error)
       Return "ERREUR : WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest1"
    EndIf

    ;WAIT
    _WinHttpReceiveResponse($hRequest)

    ;OUT if problems
    If ( _WinHttpQueryHeaders($hRequest, $WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE) <> 200 ) Then
       ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : Connexion fail" & @CR)
       Return "ERREUR : Connexion fail"
    EndIf

    ;Second : HEAD (obtain size) 
    $url_crack = _WinHttpCrackUrl($lien)
    $url = $url_crack[0] & "://" & $url_crack[2] & "/"
    $surl = $url_crack[6] & $url_crack[7]

    $hConnect = _WinHttpConnect($hOpen, $url, $INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT)
    if @error Then
       ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpConnect2 : " & @error)
       Return "ERREUR : WinHttpConnect2"
    EndIf

    $hRequest =  _WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest($hConnect, "HEAD", $surl, $WINHTTP_NO_REFERER)
    if @error Then
       ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest2 : " & @error & @CR)
       Return "ERREUR : WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest2"
    EndIf

    ;WAIT
    _WinHttpReceiveResponse($hRequest)

    ;OUT if problems
    If ( _WinHttpQueryOption($hRequest, $WINHTTP_OPTION_URL) <> $lien ) Then
       ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : Requête HEAD" &@CR)
       Return "ERREUR : Requête HEAD"
    EndIf

    $size_cloud_file = _WinHttpQueryHeaders($hRequest, $WINHTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH)
    $size_local_file = FileGetSize($local)
    GUICtrlSetData($progressbar, 0)
    GUICtrlSetState($progressbar, $GUI_SHOW)

    ;If size is different
    If $size_cloud_file <> $size_local_file Then

       ;CONNECT
       $hConnect = _WinHttpConnect($hOpen, $url, $INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT)
       if @error Then
          ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpConnect3 : " & @error & @CR)
          Return "ERREUR : WinHttpConnect3"
       EndIf

       $hRequest =  _WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest($hConnect, _
                                                "GET", _
                                                $surl, _
                                                Default, _
                                                Default, _
                                                Default)
       if @error Then
          ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest : " & @error)
          Return "ERREUR : WinHttpSimpleSendSSLRequest"
       EndIf


       $sData = Binary("")
       If _WinHttpQueryDataAvailable($hRequest) Then
          While 1

              $sChunk = _WinHttpReadData($hRequest, 2)
              If @error Then ExitLoop
              $sData &= $sChunk

              $pourcent = Int((BinaryLen($sData) / $size_cloud_file) * 100)
              GUICtrlSetData($progressbar, $pourcent)

          WEnd
      Else
          ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : WinHttpQueryDataAvailable : " & @error)
          Return "ERREUR : WinHttpQueryDataAvailable"
      EndIf

      ;Copy Byte Array to file
      FileDelete($local)
      $handle = FileOpen($local, 18)
      FileWrite($handle, $sData)
      FileClose($handle)

      ;If fail copy or download
      If ( FileGetSize($local) <> $size_cloud_file ) Then

         ConsoleWrite("ERREUR : File error" & @CR)
         Return "ERREUR : File error"

      EndIf


endfunc
```